# Prove Theorem with Groebner Basis

Tags: computational-geometry, singular, groebner-basis

I'm trying to prove some theorems using Groebner Basis (as described in Cox, Little and O'Shea  [Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387946802)   )

The mentioned book gives as an excercise to prove Pappus theorem using the given methodology, but I really can't make it work. I've tried usign Sage, Mathematica and Singular, but the Grobner Basis computation doesn't terminate.

Any idea of what can I do? Does anybody else have done this excersise before? THANKS.

This is the Singular code:

```
ring R= (0,u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7),(y,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7),dp;
poly h1=(u3 - u5)*(u4 - u6) - (u5 - u7)*(u6 - x1);
poly h2=-(u1 - u4)*u3 + (u1 - x3)*x2;
poly h3=-(u5 - x2)*(u6 - x3) + u5*u6;
poly h4=-(u2 - u4)*u3 + (u2 - x5)*x4;
poly h5=-(u7 - x4)*(x1 - x5) + u7*x1;
poly h6=-(u2 - u6)*u5 + (u2 - x7)*x6;
poly h7=-(u1 - x1)*u7 - (u7 - x6)*(x1 - x7);
poly g=(x2 - x4)*(x3 - x5) - (x4 - x6)*(x5 - x7);
poly g2=1-y*g;
ideal V=h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,g2;
std(V);
```

Comment: best of luck, looks interesting!